# If I route traffic through a SOCKS proxy, does the remote host do the DNS lookups?

Tags: dns, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I sometimes route my Web traffic through ssh using a SOCKS proxy. The purpose is to have all traffic be encrypted.

The way I do it is to open up a terminal and run this...

```
$ ssh -v -C -N -D 9000 my_own_vps_host.com
```

And in local machine's network settings I check "SOCKS proxy" and set it to 127.0.0.1 port 9000.

My question is whether my local machine is sending plaintext URLs to the DNS server, or does it send those over the encrypted connection and let the remote server handle the DNS requests?

(My local machine is a Mac if that makes any difference.)

Comment: What web browser are you using?

Comment: Usually Chrome. Occasionally Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your browser and setup, DNS queries can go through the proxy, but not always. I'd recommend using something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to analyze your traffic and see where the requests are going.

Answer (score 4):

On Firefox, it depends on whether [`network.proxy.socks_remote_dns`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.socks_remote_dns) is set. Chrome on Windows performs resolution locally.

For a reliable test, install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) and watch for DNS packets.

Note: Full URLs are *never* sent in plain; only the domain names are.